# Trying to install mmd LaTeX support – how do I get to my texmf folder?

Tags: mac, texmf

I'm trying to install multi markdown LaTeX support so I can use MathJax in my markdown, but I can't find the texmf folder on my mac. More specifically, when I run `kpsewhich` I get `~/Library/texmf`, but then when I try to access the folder through the Finder or Dock it won't show up.

I tried running `mktexlsr`, but I got

```
mktexlsr: /Users/jeff/Library/texmf: not a directory, skipping.
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: Done.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: as far as I know you need to run `mktexlsr` as superuser for it to work on `/usr/...` since a normal user can't write on those by default. Furthermore it looks like the `texmf` directory in your `Library` doesn't exist. You can simply create it. Of course there won't be anything in there, you can use it to install packages for only the current user, for instance.

Comment: From my reading of https://github.com/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown/wiki/What%27s-different-in-MultiMarkdown-3.0%3F, you don't actually need LaTeX installed if you want to use MultiMarkdown to produce something suitable for MathJaX.

Answer (score 2):

This answer only deals with part of your problem.

You are probably using OSX Lion. In the new system the `~/Library` folder is hidden by default.

You can change this permanently by issuing the following command:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Or you can make it available each time you need it. To do this, when in the Finder, go to the Go menu (my system is French and the menu is "Aller") while pressing the Option key; the Library folder will be available.

Comment: @Alan : thanks for the edit, it is now a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I never used MathJax, but the messages above indicate that you don't have write rights to the directories.

Execute the command as root.

Comment: Which on OSX means to use `sudo` from an admin account. (root is generally never enabled as an account in OS X).

Comment: But as @Frédéric says in his answer, the issue here is likely related to the fact the jefflovejapan is using Lion and the folder is made to be hidden by default.  So `mktexlsr` won't help here.